# Mother's Milk And Marriage

Tags: sharia, nikah, rada

**As salaamu alaikum**,

****Condition*** :-*
There are two women let we name them 'A' and 'B'. Women A have 3 Sons and women B have 3 daughter. women A gave milk to Women B's first daughter and to the last daughter.
my question is :-

**Question :-**
Is nikah halal for the sons of women 'A' to the second daughter of women B who did not drank milk of women 'A'

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we recommend you check out the FAQ.  As well as we recommend that you look around this site to see how things work here.  Masha'Allah you have asked a great question, and we look forward to having you as an active participant here Insha'Allah.

Comment: Good question! I always had a similar question in mind: if a man has a son from a previous marriage and a woman similarly has a daughter, and the man and woman get married, can the two kids from the previous marriages also get married since they are in no way related to each other? A question that logically follows is the kids that the parents eventually have from the new union will be half-brothers and -sisters to the kids from the previous marriages. So a very awkward question then arises that the new kids' half-brother and -sister are married to each other yet they both are mahram to them!

Comment: I guess this is a very complicated question.....

Answer (score 3):

According to Quran (http://quran.com/4/23), one can not marry his sisters due to nursing. Since the second daughter of woman B is not "sister" of woman A's sons, I think they can marry.

Comment: But their sisters has drank milk of women A so they became her real daughter n they are sisters to the second one so she might also be the real daughter of women A

Comment: The girls do not become real daughters of woman A. Quran mentions these two relations separately

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would like to point out that one or two Sucklings doesn't make [marriage unlawful](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/18), rather it [becomes unlawful](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/17) when it is known that there was five, known/distinct sucklings.  So let us assume, while still keeping in mind what I said above, that the first and last daughter of Woman B, have become haram for marriage by all 3 sons of Women A.  So the Sons of Women A are the Maharim for both the first and last daughter of Women B, while this is not the case for the second daughter of Women B, so it would be ok for the sons of Women A to approach the second daughter of women B for marriage, as well as they have to follow the rules of conduct of men with strange women, since they are not her Maharim.  I end mentioning [the narration](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/10) from the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him):

> ‏ يَحْرُمُ مِنَ الرَّضَاعَةِ مَا يَحْرُمُ مِنَ الْوِلاَدَةِ
>
> What is unlawful by reason of consanguinity is unlawful by reason of
>   fosterage

Lastly I would like to say that this answer is not a Fatwa, and is not intended to be such, and I ask Allah to forgive me of my mistakes, and to Guide us all.